# Doubts about cron on ubuntu

Tags: boot, command-line, apt, kernel, scripts

I'm learning to use Cron on Ubuntu, and I would like to ask some questions:
How can I open the terminal using cron? and then he sends a command? the command and this "sudo sinprod", I need it to be launched every day at 6:50 a.m.

Answer (score 4):

Some hints: `cron` does not open a terminal: it executes commands in the background. To execute `sinprod` daily at 6:50, open the `crontab` for editing:

```
crontab -e
```

However, since you need to run `sinprod` with root permissions, you need to open `root`'s crontab. This is the way to do that:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Then, on an empty line, enter the following:

```
50 6 * * * /path/to/sinprod
```

You will need the full path to `sinprod`. Save and exit the file, and you will see a line saying "installing new crontab".

That's it.

Comment: So even with the terminal closed the command will work?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. You don't even need to be logged on. As long as the system is running, the command will be executed.

Comment: I'd like to test it now to see if it's working, so if I just put '00 5 * * * /path/to/sinprod' it will work, I want to test it later this afternoon.

Comment: I'm not sure if cron will accept `00` for the minutes; better use a single `0`.

Comment: After the command /path/to/sinprod the computer should restart, but it is not doing so.

Comment: Look in `/var/log/syslog` why not (do `grep -i cron /var/log/syslog`).

Comment: owu, thank you very much for your help, I managed to do what I wanted! Thanks.

Comment: If my answer was useful, please tick the check mark next to it. Thanks.